# Determining if an argument is valid using equivalence transformations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I am really struggling with this problem. I am able to mentally say that the argument is valid but unable to prove it using algebra.
The problem is:

Premise 1: (p —> q) ^ (r -> s)

Premise 2:  p v s

Therefore:

Conclusion: q v s

To clarify, how can I use equivalence rules such as associativity, de Morgan, conditional etc to prove that the premises imply the conclusion.
Note, avoid using rules of inference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just updated it, let me know if it’s clearer.